# Leer carácter a carácter de un archivo .txt

Tags: java

quisiera hacer un pequeño programa a través del cual pudiera leer un archivo de texto y además lo hiciera carácter a carácter. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Con ByteArrayOutputStream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con el FileReader:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LeectorCaracteres{

public static void main(String []args){

    try(FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("c:\\data\\text.txt")){
        int caracterLeido = fileReader.read();
        while(caracterLeido!= -1) {
            char caracter = (char) caracterLeido);
            System.out.print(caracter);
            caracterLeido = fileReader.read();
        }
    }catch(IOException ex){
        System.err.println("Erorr al leer el archivo");
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
  }
}
```

Para tener en cuenta, siempre es mas eficiente si el archivo lo lees por bloques, por ejemplo utilizando un buffer con la clase BufferReader.

Espero que te sirva.